# Django deleting records from database

Tags: python, django

I have a problem. When i delete record django is deleting record with latest id. I don't know why and can't find any solution. I tried to change form action, url from pk to id but it doesn't work . It always delete the lasted recored not choosed one. Thank u for the help

models.py

```
class Usterki (models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
dodany_przez = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
samolot = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices = SAMOLOTY_CHOICES,
    default = LFA,
)
usterka = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=16,
    choices=STATUSY_CHOICES,
    default=UNACCEPTED,
    )
ograniczenia = models.CharField(
    max_length=22,
    choices = OGRANICZENIA_CHOICES,
    default = ONHOLD,
)
data_dodania = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
aktualizacja = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
zdjecie = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null = True)
naprawiona = models.BooleanField(default=False)
def __str__(self):
    return self.usterka
```

views.py

```
class UsterkaDelete(DeleteView): #poprawić bo nie działa !!!!!
model = Usterki
success_url = reverse_lazy('mojeusterki')
template_name = 'mojeusterki.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('add',views.add, name='add'),
path('usterka_edit/<int:pk>/edit/', views.usterka_edit, name='usterka_edit'),
path('<int:pk>/remove/', views.UsterkaDelete.as_view(), name='usterka_remove'),
path('mojeusterki', views.mojeusterki, name='mojeusterki'),
path('change_password', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
path('fuel', views.fuel, name='fuel'),]
```

mojeusterki.html

```
<form action="{% url 'usterka_remove' pk=usterka.pk %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-danger btn-icon-text">Usuń</button>
```

Comment: Is `usterka` always the latest object? Can you show the template where you show *multiple* items with a delete button?

Comment: Its for loop in table : '{{%for usterka in uterkis%}} {{usterka.description}} {{%endfor%}} ' and of course in a row there are two buttons delete and edit

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer is. Problem was with the modal fade id which pass only the latest id. I add {{ usterka.id}} to id of modal and now there's no problem ( to data-target and id of modal fade)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{usterka.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Usuń usterkę</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        Czy jesteś pewny, że chcesz usunąć usterkę? {{usterka.usterka}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer" >
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
                                        <form action = "{%url 'usterka_remove' pk=usterka.pk %}" method="POST">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gradient-danger btn-icon-text">Usuń</button>
                                        </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```